# Capture videos from multiple camera connected through USB port to laptop using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, video, camera, video-streaming

I'm currently building an interface that requires control to turn at least 2 cameras on/off depending on what user click on the frontend. Currently, I'm trying to see if it is possible to do the video capture through javascript or if I should do this with python (I saw some guides using OpenCV?) and somehow connect that with javascript? The cameras will be connected to a device via USB ports.

any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: The P5.js library has video capture functionality built in and is easy to implement, not sure how well it works with multiple cameras though.

Comment: I see that P5.js have video capture for built in webcam to your device, but is this applicable to external cameras plug into a device through USB?

Comment: I've not used it that way, but looking at the docs it looks like it shouldn't be a problem, you pass a constraints object to `createCapture()` and device id can be one of those constraints. https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCapture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is actually trivial to do in-browser these days.  What you're looking for is the [Media Device API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices).

For example, to get a device list:

```
const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
```

To get video from the default camera:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
```

To display that video:

```
document.querySelector('video').srcObject = stream;
```

If you want to get video from a particular device ID, you specify it in the constraints.

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    deviceId: someDeviceIdGoesHere
  }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!